# trimming 10 milliseconds from the beginning of an audio file using sox

Tags: sox, libsox

I'm trying to trim off the first 10 milliseconds of a 30+ min file.  The trim commands trims it but the output I get is 10 milliseconds.  What I want is to keep the end part of the audio file and to get rid of 10 milliseconds of the beginning of the file.

I tried using the command below:

```
sox input.wav output.wav trim 0 .010
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you use trim, the first parameter is the start time of the chunk of audio you want to keep, while the second is its length. To achieve what you want to do, assuming you file is 1800sec long (exactly 30 min), the command you have to run is:
 `sox input.wav output.wav trim 0.10 1800`

Answer (score 7):

Just

```
sox input.wav output.wav trim .010
```

Trim have two params: *start* and *length*. If the *length* param is empty it will do untill end of file